# Yielding blocks in Rails ActionView

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview, presenter, actionviewhelper

I am trying to build my Rails app following the [Presenter](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/rails-presenters/) design pattern. A part of my page includes a few divs nested inside an anchor tag, which works fine using regular html, but does not work when I try to render it using ActionView helpers.

My view looks like the following:

```
<div class="hero-container clear">
    <%= presenter.cta_background do %>
        <%= presenter.header %>

        <%= presenter.subheader %>

        <%= presenter.button %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

My presenter class:

```
class Presenter < SimpleDelegator
    def initialize(model, view)
        @model, @view = model, view
        super @model
    end

    def h
        @view
    end

    def header
        if @model.header.present?
            h.content_tag :div, @model.header
        end
    end

    def subheader
        if @model.subheader.present?
            h.content_tag :div, @model.subheader
        end
    end

    def cta_button
        if @model.text.present?
            h.content_tag :div, @model.text
        end
    end

    def cta_background
        h.link_to @model.target do
            yield
            nil
        end
    end
end
```

And it ends up rendering html that looks like:

```
<div class="hero-container clear">

        <div>Eaque ea adipisci accusantium.</div>

        <div>Sed quibusdam amet et voluptatum.</div>

        <div>Click here</div>
        <a href="/products">products</a>
</div>
```

My goal is the have the three divs **inside** the anchor tag, which is done by passing them in a block to the [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) function. Why is it not working when I call that block from another method like I am doing?